# how to write this query in Codeigniter 4 "(3*SUM(tanding.menang))+SUM(tanding.seri) AS poin"?

Tags: sql, codeigniter-4

I just learned CI4 a few days ago and I don't understand a lot, please help :'

how to write this query in Codeigniter 4 "(3*SUM(tanding.menang))+SUM(tanding.seri) AS poin" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$builder = db_connect();
$response = $builder->table('tanding')->select("(3*SUM(tanding.menang))+SUM(tanding.seri) AS poin")->get()->getResult();
```